# Play Idea failing - no sbt-idea plugin for this version of sbt 0.11.3

Tags: scala, playframework, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-idea

I'm stuck.

I've on a Mac and have installed the typesafe stack with brew

I've created a new play project using **play new appname** and all is fine.

I'm trying to import it into intelliJ using **play idea** - but when I do this I get the following error;

```
[error] no sbt-idea plugin for this version of sbt - 0.11.3
```

I have play! 2.0.3 and sbt 0.11.3

Any idea how I actually fix this?

Comment: Have you tried overriding SBT to 0.11.2 in the build.properties file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, ensure you've followed: [the official installation instructions](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/blob/sbt-0.11/README.md)

This will currently result in the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin$.ideaSettings()Lscala/collection/Seq; at
sbt.PlayCommands$class.intellijCommandSettings(PlayCommands.scala:214)
```

Current fix is to downgrade to play 2.0.1 by editing the project.plugins.sbt file thusly:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.0.1")
```

This seems to resolve the problem for now.

Comment: This was answered by the comments in the previous answer, figured I'd just agglomerate it in one answer post.

Comment: I've reported this issue as bug #804 : https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/804-namespace-collisions-of-incompatible-typesafe-sbt-idea-fork